# javascript + jquery + setinterval + animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, setinterval

I'm having a problem with setInterval and jquery animate.  Here is my code:

```
function slides1() {

    ...

    $("table#agah1").animate({
        "left": first1
    }, "slow");
    $("table#agah2").animate({
        "left": first2
    }, "slow");
}

$(function () {
    cyc = setInterval("slides1()", 3000);
});
```

When switch to another browser tab, and return after a time, the animation keep doing it without delay, for the time I've been away from the tab, and then act correct. I've added these also without any luck:

```
$(window).focus(function () {
    jQuery.fx.off = false;
    cyc = setInterval("slides1()", 3000);
});
$(window).blur(function () {
    jQuery.fx.off = true;
    window.clearInterval(cyc);
});
```

Comment: not the issue here, but pass a function reference, don't pass strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Newer versions of jQuery use `requestAnimationFrame` callbacks to handle effects, and browsers don't process those on hidden tabs.</strike>

In the meantime, your `setInterval` events are still happening, causing more animations to get queued up.

Rather than use `setInterval` to schedule the animations, use the "completion callback" of the last animation to trigger the next cycle, with a `setTimeout` if necessary.

```
function slides1() {

    ...

    $("table#agah1").animate({
        "left": first1
    }, "slow");
    $("table#agah2").animate({
        "left": first2
    }, "slow", function() {
       setTimeout(slides1, 2000); // start again 2s after this finishes
    });
}

$(function () {
    setTimeout(slides1, 3000);    // nb: not "slides1()"
});
```

This will ensure that there's a tight coupling between the interanimation delay and the animations themselves, and avoid any issues with `setTimeout` getting out of sync with the animations.

Comment: requestAnimationFrame is not an option. it had many bugs, and still wont work like a charm in cross browsers:http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9381

Comment: @HabibS ah - I didn't spot that they had reverted that.  In any event the code above is preferable - it couples together the animation and the timeouts in a way that should prevent the problem you're seeing.

Comment: @HabibS in any event, your question is unclear.  Do you _want_ the animations to start from scratch whenever you switch tab?

Comment: Your second suggestion actually worked. The problem is that all jquery animation/fade/... commands + setinterval will be on hold if page blur occure, and will do all the loop without delay after page focus.