# d3.js: Transition callback is not called for enter()

Tags: javascript, animation, browser, callback, d3.js

I am using a modified version of this [D3 tutorial bar chart](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html).

What is important for me is that animations should not stack upon leaving the browser window then trigger all of them when the window is in focus again, causing the browser to hang, so as per [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671284/javascript-jquery-setinterval-animation), I'm trying to use a `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` that should be called when the animation has ended.

I'm having problems with the callbacks and I don't understand why the simple `transition()` callback is working, but not the `enter()` for example.

After I set up the chart & scale, here's how my initializing function looks like:

```
function redrawTimer() {
  data.shift();
  data.push(next());
  redraw(function(){
    console.log('callback');
    setTimeout(redrawTimer, 1500);
  });
}

setTimeout(redrawTimer, 1500);

function redraw(callback) {

  var rect = chart.selectAll("rect")
      .data(data, function(d) { return d.time; });

  rect.enter().insert("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i + 1) - .5; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return h - y(d.value) - .5; })
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("fill", "white")
      .attr("fill-opacity", 0.2)
    .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i) - .5; })
      .each('end', callback); // Doesn't work at all

  rect.transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i) - .5; });
      //.each('end', callback); // Works but for each of the 50 elements

  rect.exit().transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i - 1) - .5; })
      //.each('end', callback) // This only works after the first transition so using it to trigger the next data point is useless
      .remove();
}
```

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zinkkrysty/ahzuQ/) for fiddling with the code :)

It may be that I do not perfectly understand how `transition()` works differently on either `enter()` or `exit()` or just the selector.

Can you enlighten me?

If you can make the callback work, but doesn't solve my problem stated above (animations on browser leaving), please help me with that as well, as I'll upvote your comments/answer.

**Edit**:

I managed to get rid of the animation queue buildup by testing for which element the transition has ended, and only take the last one:

```
rect.transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i) - .5; })
      .each('end', function(d, i){
        if(i == 49)
          callback();
      });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Elements can only have *one* active transition at a time. The `rect.enter().transtition()` immediately gets overwritten by the `rect.transition()` (`rect` is the update selection which also contains the entering elements!). Therefore `rect.enter().transition().each('end', callback)` never gets called.

For more information see the [API documentation on transitions](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions) or [Mike's tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/transition/#per-element).

Comment: It would make sense, but what puzzles me is that the `attr("x", function..)` after the `enter()` is triggered as expected, 50 times if I put a `console.log` inside the function. But not the end callback. Also, your answer would mean that the tutorial's code is faulty.

Comment: `rect.enter().attr("x", ...)` is not the same as `rect.enter().transition().attr("x", ...)`.

But oddly, each call to `.attr("x", ...)` runs. My guess is that the `rect.enter().transition()` gets started and subsequently canceled by `rect.transition()`. Therefore each `.attr("x", ...)` gets called but the `.each("end", ...)` on the enter selection won't.

To avoid confusion, just remove the enter transition. The code works perfectly fine without it.

If you want to have _different_ transitions for the enter and update, specify the update transition _before_ the enter transitions.

Comment: Someone should update this tutorial then, it's very misleading by writing the transition twice http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html